# HTTP PUT method with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm struggling with `NSURLSession` class introduced in iOS 7 SDK and I'm stuck at a point, where I need to call my *REST API* with `PUT` method.

I've already implemented `GET` and `POST` methods, which are working fine using this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:httpMethod]; // GET/POST works, PUT does not
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            // do something here
            ( ... )
        } else {
            // process error
            ( ... )
        }
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
```

Unfortunately, setting `httpMethod` to `PUT` doesn't seem to work (it behaves as `GET`). Calling contents of *url from cURL console works fine - so the path to API is OK.

How can I create valid `PUT` request to my API using `NSURLSession`?

Comment: Have you looked at what is being sent with an analyzer such as Charles Proxy?

Comment: Where is the Body set? `- (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data`

Comment: The PUT request here works fine, where do you set the body?

Comment: An Aside: I have spend a lot of time with various web services and the one thing I always use is Charles Proxy. It let's me immediately see what is really sent and received. When I am doing this type of work I always have Charles open and recording all traffic to and from the server I am working with. In this case I would immediately see there is no data sent.

Comment: Further to my comment, if you make your PUT request to `http://httpbin.org/put` you'll see a JSON response using your exact code. NSURLSessionDataTask has no issues with PUT.

Comment: @David Wow, I was not aware of http://httpbin.org, thanks!

Comment: Square's PonyDebugger also helps with these issues, though it [doesn't support NSURLSession yet](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger/issues/92)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the data with `NSMutableURLRequest` `setHTTPBody` method, the same as with POST.

```
- (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data
```

Comment: The problem i've experienced originated from poorly written server-side API. I've had to pass the same arguments in HTTPBody as well as in NSURL as parameters separated with &.

Thanks guys for http://httpbin.org and CharlesProxy!

Comment: "Poorly written server-side API", been there. Even was given a curl GET command that had body data.